# ¿Tiene sentido una acepción que no explica significado alguno?

Tags: significado, conjunciones, rae, dle

Acabo de descubrir en el diccionario de la RAE una palabra que tiene una acepción que no es una acepción, ya que no explica en realidad lo que significa la palabra.

> **[pues](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UawHjxX)**
>
> 6. conj. U. con diversos significados dependientes del tono con que se pronuncia.

Me parece muy bien que la palabra *pues* tenga diversos significados, pero ¿cuáles son? Entiendo que pueda ser complicado explicar los significados de una palabra dependiendo del tono. No es lo mismo decirle a tu pareja "ay, *tonto*, pero ¿por qué te has molestado?" en plan juguetón que decirle "¿pero tú eres *tonto* o qué?" en plan seco a alguien. Misma palabra, diferentes entonaciones, diversos significados. Y el significado de *tonto* en el primer ejemplo ni siquiera lo veo claro en el DLE.

Este significado además no es reciente. Comenzó en 1869 con una nota en una de las acepciones:

> Tiene otras aplicaciones que enseña el uso.

Y se estableció como acepción propia en 1884:

> Tiene además otras varias apilcaciones que enseña el uso y que difícilmente podrían explicarse, porque á veces su significación depende sólo del tono con que es pronunciada.

Adonde quiero llegar es que, al igual que las acepciones de *[tonto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a1laMnE)* mencionadas antes dependen de la entonación y aun así ese detalle no aparece en el diccionario, ¿no debería esta acepción de *pues* desaparecer también? A fin de cuentas no dice absolutamente nada, básicamente te dice que te las apañes e infieras el significado por ti mismo. Con acepciones así, ¿para qué queremos el diccionario?

Y más aún: si el diccionario de la RAE se confecciona usando como base la lengua escrita, hasta el punto de que las palabras registradas necesitan aparecer en textos durante al menos cinco años y de forma consistente y amplia, ¿a cuento de qué una acepción que habla sobre el tono con el que se pronuncia, si en la lengua escrita no hay tonos? Esto rompería la con la filosofía del diccionario, permitiendo una acepción basada en la expresión oral.

Pregunta pues: ¿creéis que tiene sentido esta acepción y debería dejarse en el DLE? ¿O creéis que la RAE haría mejor retirándola del diccionario ya que no especifica significado alguno?

---

> NOTA: Esta pregunta puede entrar dentro del terreno de la subjetividad, pero considero que aun así es una subjetividad constructiva que se puede argumentar con razonamientos, cosa que permiten [las reglas del sitio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Como parte de dicho razonamiento se podría intentar dar respuesta a una pregunta relacionada: ¿hay otras palabras en el DLE con acepciones similares?

Comment: En ese caso se podría reemplazar "tono con que se pronuncia" por "contexto".

Comment: Me gustaría ver un registro de las discusiones que habrá habido entre los académicos para acabar poniendo esto como definición de una acepción. Se echan de menos algunos ejemplos para hacerse una idea de a qué se refieren.

Answer (score 1):

La acepción de *pues* en el DLE le indica al usuario del DLE que no conoce la palabra (!) que no debe esperar una definición clara sino prestar atención al uso. En este sentido yo diría que es una acepción útil. Para usuarios secundarios (por ejemplo, personas que están aprendiendo a hablar el idioma y que utilizan el DLE, o las personas que enseñan o diseñan cursos de castellano, o que escriben gramáticas), esta acepción "que no dice nada" tiene la virtud de cortar por lo sano la búsqueda. Les dice: si quieres entender o enseñar qué significa *pues*, deberás hacerlo con ejemplos de uso, de manera similar a como se aprenden la mayoría de las palabras comunes de todo idioma, que no son definidas explícitamente por nadie.

Comment: Entiendo tu argumento, pero permíteme un comentario. Si la RAE confecciona el DLE según el uso de las palabras en la expresión escrita, ¿tiene sentido una acepción que se refiere al **tono** de la palabra? Esto indicaría claramente su uso en la expresión oral (en la lengua escrita no hay tonos), y por tanto iría en contra del espíritu del diccionario.

Comment: Sí, la forma de la acepción podría haber sido mejor. En la lengua escrita también se pueden sugerir significados y connotaciones sin recurrir a definiciones, y eso debería figurar en la acepción del DLE.

Comment: Aunque no exista el tono como tal, entiendo que se refieren a contexto. Al fin y al cabo, no creo que en la misma frase, con las mismas palabras y el mismo contexto cambie el significado de la palabra "pues" dependiendo unicamente del tono.

Comment: @Charlie El diccionario debe dar cuenta de ello si el tono (hablado) afecta al significado (el acento tónico [se define como una elevación del tono](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0NDBxAs) y se refleja gráficamente por la tilde o su ausencia). De todas formas, la 5ª acepción de [_tono_](https://dle.rae.es/?id=a15EQrS) reza "carácter o modo particular de la expresión y del estilo de un texto según el asunto que trata o el estado de ánimo que pretende reflejar", que tiene que ver con el contexto que decían y se refiere a lo escrito. Mira la 2ª también. No es muy objetivo, pero hay que reflejarlo.